# Data Visualization - showing a Tree in HTML, CSS, JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, information-visualization

I have a tree based dataset that I want to visualize in my webpage. the data is just your basic tree: there is a parent node, with subnodes and then subnodes of those nodes.

I am looking for a package to visualize the data in a tree format. does anyone know of one? [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html) has one, but Im wondering if there ar other alternatives

Comment: When you say 'tree format', are you looking for an org chart type of format?  When you say 'tree', I'm thinking of jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/) or something like that, which doesn't support an org chart format.

Comment: not so much like that. i want it to be aesthetically pleasing. its for a tutoring website and will display a students goals and subgoals. so Goal A could be "get an A in math" and subgoals would be "get a 93% on the midterm exam" and "finish all homeworks on time" the structure you've laid out is more of a directory type. (though good to know that exists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit is pretty sweet for web visualization and animation. Check out the [demo page](http://thejit.org/demos/), particularly SpaceTree, RGraph, and HyperTree.

Comment: Here is an updated link to the InfoVis Toolkit: http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html